# How to add Terminal Object in your Website?

Tags: shell, web, terminal

Website like [koding](http://koding.com) , [codeschool](http://codeschool.com) ,[cloud9](http://c9.io) and many others have the ability to access their server via terminal.

Is it  really terminal application in sandbox?

How did they do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this](https://serverfault.com/questions/18533/how-to-enable-shell-acess-over-http-web-browser)

The terminal access can be provided by having a client server mechanism.

Here a server is running at the linux machine and client is browser. 
server executes command on behalf of client.

Take a look at [ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/)

Comment: Thankyou, but as I download the ajaxterm the response is 404 not found